# What is a common REST way to request a list of resources that all exclude a propert, like an outer join

Tags: rest, outer-join

For my specific case, I have `users` which can be `friends` with each other.
I have a users table:

```
| Id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
```

And a `friends` table:

```
| Id | From_User_Id | To_User_Id |
+----+--------------+------------+
| 1  |       1      |      2     |
| 2  |       3      |      1     |
```

And I want to get all users NOT friends with a user. So for `User 1` the result returned will be `User 4`.

What should a REST GET request look like to retrieve this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
GET /users/1/notfriends
```

The important point is however, that the representation at `/users/1` should **link** to this to be "proper" REST.

Comment: I am using EmberJS, and with the current Ember Data it doesn't allow links. The closest I can get is `GET /users?notfriends=1`. But this should work.